# How to install gcc-5.5 in ubuntu? how can I switch gcc version arbitrarily in ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation, gcc

Sorry, gays. I forgot to tell you the purpose of installing the old version of gcc, because I need to use the sofeware gpgpu-sim( https://github.com/gpgpu-sim/gpgpu-sim_distribution) to simulate the GPU, and may need it to implement some of the contents of the paper.

When I input `sudo apt install gcc-5.5` in my terminal, it just display show the following picture:

```
➜  ZhouPengfei sudo apt-get install gcc-5.5 g++-5.5 gcc-11.4 g++-11.4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package gcc-5.5
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gcc-5.5'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-5.5'
E: Unable to locate package g++-5.5
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'g++-5.5'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-5.5'
E: Unable to locate package gcc-11.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'gcc-11.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'gcc-11.4'
E: Unable to locate package g++-11.4
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'g++-11.4'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'g++-11.4'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Hcxt.png)

So I try to install it manually from the Web http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/g/ .
I install these files from the website:

```
➜  gcc-5 ll
total 28M
cpp-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
g++-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
gcc-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
gcc-5-base_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libasan2_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libcilkrts5_7.5.0-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb
libgcc-5-dev_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libisl15_0.18-4_amd64.deb
libmpx0_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libstdc++-5-dev_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb
libubsan0_7.5.0-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

And I use dpkg to install it `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. And it display something:

```
(Reading database ... 222015 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack cpp-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cpp-5 (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) over (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package g++-5.
Preparing to unpack g++-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking g++-5 (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package gcc-5.
Preparing to unpack gcc-5_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-5 (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack gcc-5-base_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking gcc-5-base:amd64 (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) over (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack libasan2_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libasan2:amd64 (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) over (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libcilkrts5:amd64.
Preparing to unpack libcilkrts5_7.5.0-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libcilkrts5:amd64 (7.5.0-6ubuntu2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgcc-5-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack libgcc-5-dev_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libgcc-5-dev:amd64 (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) ...
Preparing to unpack libisl15_0.18-4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libisl15:amd64 (0.18-4) over (0.18-4) ...
Preparing to unpack libmpx0_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libmpx0:amd64 (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) over (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libstdc++-5-dev:amd64.
Preparing to unpack libstdc++-5-dev_5.5.0-12ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libstdc++-5-dev:amd64 (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libubsan0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack libubsan0_7.5.0-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libubsan0:amd64 (7.5.0-6ubuntu2) ...
Setting up gcc-5-base:amd64 (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libasan2:amd64 (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcilkrts5:amd64:
 libcilkrts5:amd64 depends on gcc-7-base (= 7.5.0-6ubuntu2); however:
  Package gcc-7-base is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libcilkrts5:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgcc-5-dev:amd64:
 libgcc-5-dev:amd64 depends on libcilkrts5 (>= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1); however:
  Package libcilkrts5:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgcc-5-dev:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up libisl15:amd64 (0.18-4) ...
Setting up libmpx0:amd64 (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libstdc++-5-dev:amd64:
 libstdc++-5-dev:amd64 depends on libgcc-5-dev (= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1); however:
  Package libgcc-5-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libstdc++-5-dev:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libubsan0:amd64:
 libubsan0:amd64 depends on gcc-7-base (= 7.5.0-6ubuntu2); however:
  Package gcc-7-base is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package libubsan0:amd64 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up cpp-5 (5.5.0-12ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g++-5:
 g++-5 depends on libstdc++-5-dev (= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1); however:
  Package libstdc++-5-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package g++-5 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of gcc-5:
 gcc-5 depends on libgcc-5-dev (= 5.5.0-12ubuntu1); however:
  Package libgcc-5-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package gcc-5 (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libcilkrts5:amd64
 libgcc-5-dev:amd64
 libstdc++-5-dev:amd64
 libubsan0:amd64
 g++-5
 gcc-5
```

Athough many errors were prompted during this process, when I executed the next command, it was successfully installed:

- `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 30`,
- `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 30`.

And it displays:

```
➜ gcc-5 sudo update-alternatives --config gcc                                
There is only one alternative in link group gcc (providing /usr/bin/gcc): /usr/bin/gcc-5
Nothing to configure.

➜ gcc-5 sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5 30
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/g++-5 to provide /usr/bin/g++ (g++) in auto mode
```

And I input `gcc --version`, it shows:

```
gcc-5 gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1) 5.5.0 20171010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

And after I input `g++ --version`, it shows:

```
➜  gcc-5 g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 5.5.0-12ubuntu1) 5.5.0 20171010
Copyright (C) 2015 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Next, the problem comes. No matter what I download, it will prompt that there is a dependency problem. It may be that there is a problem with the installation of gcc-5.5 just now. If I want to install any other software, I need to execute `sudo apt --fix-broken install` to fix this problem. But the result is the gcc just installed is uninstalled again.

Obviously, I cannot freely switch gcc version. Can Anyone help me? I'm going to be tortured crazy.
I kept googling for solutions to these problems, but I didn't find one that worked for me I didn't know if I had a fatal error somewhere.

There is something about my system:

```
➜  gcc-5 neofetch
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.               graduation_project@moonlight01 
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`           ------------------------------ 
      -+ssssssssssssssssssyyssss+-         OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS x86_64 
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.       Host: ThinkSystem SR650 -[7X06CTO1WW]- 07 
   /ssssssssssshdmmNNmmyNMMMMhssssss/      Kernel: 6.2.0-37-generic 
  +ssssssssshmydMMMMMMMNddddyssssssss+     Uptime: 8 days, 5 hours, 21 mins 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhmNMMMNhssssssss/    Packages: 1849 (dpkg), 11 (snap) 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Shell: zsh 5.8.1 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   Resolution: 1024x768 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   Terminal: /dev/pts/0 
ossyNMMMNyMMhsssssssssssssshmmmhssssssso   CPU: Intel Xeon Silver 4216 (64) @ 799MHz 
+sssshhhyNMMNyssssssssssssyNMMMysssssss+   GPU: NVIDIA Tesla T4 
.ssssssssdMMMNhsssssssssshNMMMdssssssss.   Memory: 8182MiB / 128281MiB 
 /sssssssshNMMMyhhyyyyhdNMMMNhssssssss/
  +sssssssssdmydMMMMMMMMddddyssssssss+                             
   /ssssssssssshdmNNNNmyNMMMMhssssss/                              
    .ossssssssssssssssssdMMMNysssso.
      -+sssssssssssssssssyyyssss+-
        `:+ssssssssssssssssss+:`
            .-/+oossssoo+/-.
```

Who can help me? Please. Why am I so stupid ??

Comment: Regarding the question you've asked to the answers below, I personally wouldn't use Docker for this.  I still worry that it isn't isolated enough from the rest of the system.  Is it possible for you just install an older version of Ubuntu on to your system?  And if that's not possible, the better option (I think) is to keep your 22.04 system but run an older Ubuntu image on it using `virtualbox`.  A VM would be sufficiently isolated.  You could also consider posting an Issue in the repository rather than asking here -- I mean, it is their software and they might be looking after it still.

Comment: @Ray I know what you mean. But I'm doing it on the server. There is no way to use a VM. The repository seems old, I'm not sure if they are still maintaining it.

Comment: I think Virtualbox will work on a server (i.e., there might be command-line options equivalent to the GUI).  As for the repository being old, I still think it is worth asking.  Their 2020 paper has 170 citations and two other papers are on arXiv, presumably waiting for a submission some day.  Even if it was 10 years' old research, I always think asking the developers is worth it since there might a student working on it that isn't yet made public / published.  Surely you can link your Issue to this page so that they can see what trouble you're having.

Comment: @Ray Yeah, you are right. Virtualbox can work on a server. And I ask them this question. I think the best resolution is to use Docker. Thank you for taking the time to answer the question. Thank you very much. Your advice is great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's remind you of two fundamental elements of Debian-based distros: They are based upon snapshots in time, and they are not black-boxes.

- Each Operating System (OS) has different elements and different limitations. Any change of OS therefore involves a learning curve. Ubuntu has never claimed to be a drop-in replacement for other OS.

**Snapshots in time**: All the software in a release is based around a single set of dependencies. Those dependencies cannot be changed. Change occurs during the next snapshot (release).

gcc is a dependency of many other packages -- changing it will break your system...as you have discovered. The only solution to save your system is to change gcc back to the appropriate version for that release of Ubuntu.

**Not a black box**: The operating system uses the same tools and dependencies as many applications. The line between OS and applications is vague. When you change key dependencies, you break applications...and the OS also.

---

Can you have multiple versions of gcc or any other key dependency? Sure. But you must be very careful: You are on the edge of breaking your system. Like the edge of a cliff, precautions are wise.

- Don't change defaults.
- Consider installing other versions using a non-Deb method, and perhaps to a different location (like `/usr/local/`)
- Know how to revert changes safely.
- Backups.

Comment: @Kirito Just to elaborate if I may ... `gcc` is actually an optional package and not installed by default nor anything installed by default depends on it AFAIK ... if `apt rdepends --installed gcc` returns packages then those are installed by you ... It's rather it's dependencies that might conflict with other system packages dependencies and too old versions might result in a messy situation.

Comment: @user535733  g++ is the optional one, gcc is certainly installed by default -- check /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you. I get it. But I have to use some old gcc to compile some software. When I installed it before, the compilation was successful, but in the subsequent process, it will be very troublesome if I want to use other version of gcc. I need to go through the process again.

Comment: It is just the first time for me to use the software(https://github.com/gpgpu-sim/gpgpu-sim_distribution). So may I try it in the docker?

Comment: @user535733 I think what you said makes sense, but I think the problem I encountered is how to successfully compile old software, and compiling this software requires a low version of gcc. But I have compromised and just use docker.

Answer (score 2):

Installing ancient software directly on your distribution is never the preferred way to go. [GCC 5.5](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-5/) is over 6 years old, and is thus considered antiquated.

Experiments with historic software versions are best done in a container or VM, using a guest OS that matches the period of the old software you want to test. In this case, maybe a containerized copy of Ubuntu 16.04 would be a better environment to test this.

In any case, as @user535733 correctly states, installing incompatible software on your base system is very likely to break it.

And for good measure: On Ubuntu 22.04, only GCC 11 (default) and GCC 10 (backported in Universe) are compatible versions.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. My purpose happens to be to use software from about 6 years ago to simulate something. https://github.com/gpgpu-sim/gpgpu-sim_distribution

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an XY problem.  Why do you want such an old version of gcc?   You didn't explain this in your question, so it's hard to address this directly.  You might be better off figuring out what options to give to a current gcc to get the same results.

As explained in other answers, installing a backdated version of gcc  on your from old repositories is an extremely bad idea.   Changing your system default gcc will break kernel updates and driver builds even if you change to a supported version of gcc.  Just Don't Do It.

Alternatives to this are:

- Hand compile gcc and install it in /usr/local/gcc-$version or /opt/gcc-$version  (this is a lot of work!!)
- Change the build options (with environment variables probably) to use the alternate gcc instead of changing system default.  The environment-modules package makes this easy.
- Install a containerized OS of an appropriate version (as suggested in the other answer, but this takes a lot of memory and disk space, but this is probably the easiest option)

Using old software is rarely justifiable.  The only valid justification I've seen is to test for bugs in old software.   If you aren't seeking old bugs, you shouldn't be using old software, you should figure out how to use current software instead.

Comment: Sorry and Thank you for taking the time to answer. I have edited my question. The reason for installing old gcc is that I need to use very old software(https://github.com/gpgpu-sim/gpgpu-sim_distribution) to simulate gpu. I know it is not a good choice to use an old version of gcc. Maybe I should try it in docker.

Comment: Docker is one of several good container options.  Singularity (aka Apptainer) is a bit simpler and would also work.

Comment: Yeal. I tried using docker, and it worked perfectly to do what I wanted, so I decided to use docker.